# How to switch git's branch in Qt Creator correctly?

Tags: git, qt-creator, open-source

I'm trying to build Blender application from Source here: git.blender.org/blender.git

For now I can build blender from master branch, and it works fine. But I have troubles with 2.8 branch - it builds, but not run.

I’m using ubuntu 18.04 and Qt Creator. I set up all like it described [here](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Developer_Intro/Environment/Linux_CMake_QtCreator).

In menu I select *Tools -> git -> local storage -> branches*, select  2.8
branch here, when in the menu *git -> fetch* and  *git -> pull*.

When I build, and it always build with success, but shows a lot of warnings, but I don’t think that is critical, so I just ignore this.

When i try to run blender, and it crashes with error:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::logic_error'
     what():  basic_string::_M_construct null not valid
```

So, maybe I’m doing something wrong? Maybe, I miss something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I solved this problem bay creating new folder for the brunch.

Setup new folder like this

```
cd ~/blender-build/blender 

mkdir ~/other-build 
git worktree add ~/other-build/blender master 
ln -s ~/blender-build/lib ~/other-build/lib 

cd ~/other-build/blender 
make
```

when build Qt project

```
cd ~/other-build/build
python3 ../blender/build_files/cmake/cmake_qtcreator_project.py
```